# Parcelable, what is newArray for?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I am implementing Parcelable in order to transmit some simple data throughout an Intent.
However, There is one method in the Parcelable interface that I don't understand at all : `newArray()`.
It does not have any relevant documentation & is not even called in my code when I parcel/deparcel my object.

Sample Parcelable implementation :

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
     }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
     }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator&lt;MyParcelable&gt; CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator&lt;MyParcelable&gt;() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

So, my question is :  what is this method for ? and when is it called ?
Is there any point in doing something else than `return new MyParcelable[size];` in that method ?

Comment: had the same question.. cheers to inquisitive minds :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a function to be called when you try to deserialize an array of `Parcelable` objects and for each single object `createFromParcel` is called.

Answer (score 5):

It is there to prepare the typed array without all the generics stuff. That's it.
Returning just the standard `return new MyParcelable[size];` is fine.

It is normal, that you never call it yourself. However, by calling something like `Bundle.getParcelableArray()` you end up in this method indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

newArray is responsible to create an array of our type of the appropriate size